# How can I provide an assistant the rights to manage my Firebase Distribution Testers list?

Tags: firebase-app-distribution

I want to enable someone to manage testers and groups.  What are the steps to provide the minimum level of permissions to enable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebaser here - you can create a [custom role](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles-custom) with specific Firebase permissions and then assign that to a member of your organization.

Looking at the individual products' [management permissions for App Distribution](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/permissions#app-distro), the following permissions should enable this for you:

```
firebaseappdistro.testers.list
firebaseappdistro.testers.update
firebaseappdistro.groups.list
firebaseappdistro.groups.update
```

Note that the App Distribution permissions are in beta as of now, and that you will need to add other permissions to your custom role to make sure it works - see the [required permissions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/permissions) section of the Firebase IAM permissions page.